# Update a component's class

Tags: angular

This is my homecomponent:

```
<button (click)="onClick('Hello')" [ngClass]="{'positive': connectedToWWE, 'negative' : !connectedToWWE}"> Hello! Click
Me! </button>
```

This is the ts file:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  connectedToWWE: boolean;

  constructor(myService: MyService) {
    this.connectedToWWE = false;
  }

  onClick(message: string) {
    this.myService.broadcastMessage(message);
    this.connectedToWWE = !this.connectedToWWE;

  }


  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log("NgChange is triggered!....");
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myService.message.subscribe(message => {
      if (message.data === "Connected") {
        this.connectedToWWE = !this.connectedToWWE;
      }
      console.log(message);
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.connectedToWWE = !this.connectedToWWE;
    }, 4000);
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I click on the button or when the timeout triggers, button's class will be changed and rendered properly. But, when I receive the "Connected" message, it is not working! Why?

*********UPDATE********

This issue is resolved if I injnect ChangeDetectorRef to HomeComponent as **cd** and call detectChanges:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.connectedToWWE = false;
}
this.myService.message.subscribe(message => {
    if (message.data === "Connected") {
        this.connectedToWWE = !this.connectedToWWE;
        this.cd.detectChanges();
    }
    console.log(message);
});
```

Is it an Angular bug or I am missing something?

Comment: check what you have in `message` according to your code you publish a `string` but expect an object with `data` property

Comment: It does not publish a string. The variable bc is the broadcast channel. The first line inside onClick sends a message to the other side of the channel. However, it toggles the boolean value as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the message.data is equal to "Connected"?
If the if is never executed, the value cannot change in that case.

Also, you can add a console.log to both the if and the onClick. as shown below:

```
onClick(message: string) {
  this.genesys.broadcastMessage(message);
  this.connectedToWWE = !this.connectedToWWE;
  console.log('onClick ran!');
}
```

In the genesys subscribe:

```
this.genesys.message.subscribe(message => {
  if (message.data === "Connected") {
    this.connectedToWWE = !this.connectedToWWE;
    console.log('genesys.message.subscribe ran!');
  }
  console.log(message);
});
```

There's a posibility that onClick is changing the value too quickly and the logs would help you understand it if they are as not as expected.

Comment: I confirmed that the message is indeed "Connected" and the if statement is a hit.